# Rescaling of a linear program

Tags: computer-science, linear-programming, programming

I have a linear program and I need to check if it has a solution.

Some coefficients entering the program are **much smaller than others**. E.g., some coefficients are of the order $10^{-10}$, while the others are of the order of $10^{-2}$.

When coefficients are very small, many optimization algorithms do not work properly and, to address the issue, some of them arbitrarily drop coefficients with small values.

Therefore, I need to rescale the linear program.

However, if I rescale by multiplying everything, e.g., by $10^7$, the small coefficients become acceptable, but the others become too large.

**What can be a correct way of rescaling?**

---

**This is the linear program written in a compact way:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1)\quad  A  \text{ }x = b\\
&(2)\quad C \text{ }x\leq c\\
\end{aligned}
$$

$A$ and $C$ contain the coefficients with magnitude of different order as mentioned above. $A$ is $m\times n$ with $n>m$. $C$ is $j\times n$ with $n>j$. $A$ has rank $m$. $C$ has rank $h<j$.

If I had only $A$, I think I could use the full reduced form of $A$. But, here, I also have $C$.

---

**This is the linear program in details (if needed):**

The unknown of the linear program is an array $\lambda$ of size $\overbrace{(K+1)\times (K+1) \times ...\times (K+1)}^{D \text{ times}}\times L$. I denote its $(k_1,k_2,...,k_D,y)-th$ element by $\lambda(k_1,k_2,...,k_D,y)$.

The coefficients of the linear program are three arrays, $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\delta$.

$\alpha$ has size $\overbrace{(K+1)\times (K+1) \times ...\times (K+1)}^{D \text{ times}}\times \overbrace{L \times L}^{2 \text{  times}}$. I denote its $(k_1,k_2,...,k_D,y, y')$-th element by $\alpha(k_1,k_2,...,k_D,y, y')$.

$\beta$ has size $\overbrace{(K+1)\times (K+1) \times ...\times (K+1)}^{D \text{ times}}$. I denote its $(k_1,k_2,...,k_D)$-th element by $\beta(k_1,k_2,...,k_D)$.

$\delta$ has size $L\times 1$. I denote its $y$-th element by $\delta(y)$.

This is the linear program:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1) \quad  \sum_{k_1=0}^K  \sum_{k_2=0}^K... \sum_{k_D=0}^K \lambda(k_1,..., k_D,y) \alpha(k_1,...,k_D,y, y')\geq 0 \quad \forall y,y' \text{ with } y\neq y'\\
&(2) \quad \lambda(k_1,..., k_D,y) \geq 0 \quad \forall k_1,..., k_D, y\\
& (3) \sum_{y=1}^L \lambda(k_1,..., k_D,y) =1\quad \forall k_1,..., k_D\\
& (4) \sum_{k_1=0}^K  \sum_{k_2=0}^K... \sum_{k_D=0}^K \lambda(k_1,..., k_D,y) \beta(k_1,..., k_D)=\delta(y) \quad \forall y
\end{aligned}
$$

The arrays that some very small numbers when $K$ is large are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that linearly rescaling will work, as rescaling is approximately orthogonal to the underlying double precision.

This is because IEEE764 doubles store floating point numbers as $(\pm 1) x^y$ where $x$ has up to $53$ bits of precision and $y$ has up to $11$ bits. The significand $x$ carries only about 15 base-10 digits of precision. Scaling each coefficient approximately only effects the exponents $y$, but the precision issues you're seeing are due to insufficient precision in the significands.

If the coefficients of the matrices $A$ and $C$ vary by $8$ orders of magnitude, then double precision is incapable of recognizing cancellation among the larger coefficients. For example, if the $a_i$ are each of size $10^8$ and the $b_i$ are each roughly constant, then $a_1 a_2 + b_1 \approx a_1 a_2$ in double precision arithmetic, as $b_1$ is too small to affect the precision of the significant in $a_1 a_2$.

It might be possible that using higher precision (e.g. 128-bit quad precision, or arbitrary precision) would work. It might also be necessary to try to modify your linear program to be better conditioned --- but this can be hard.

Comment: Thanks, I agree on the fact that linear rescaling will not work. I'm not sure how to use the rest of your answer. Suppose I want to solve the LP in Matlab by using the MOSEK solver. What does it mean using higher precision?

Comment: I don't use matlab and can't say. For programming/tooling questions, I suggest you ask somewhere with people familiar with those tools.